# Swift - Generic models for different table view cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics

I'm working on a table view (similar to that of Facebook's Messenger) in which I have different cell types (image, text, video, etc..)
What I'm trying to archive is, I want to declare a list of `message model`, and I'll configure the *tableView* so that the cell will be determined and configured by the model itself. In order to do that, I need to somehow tell the `model` which *UITableViewCell* class it associates it. Basically I want to have a protocol like this:

```
protocol ChatMessageDisplayable {
   static var myCellType: UITableViewCell { get } //Defines the UITableViewCell class this model is associated with
   func configure(cell: /*the associated cell type*/) // Let the model itself configure the cell.
}
```

Then I in my ViewController, I will declare an array

`messageModels = [ChatMessageDisplayable]`

And my UITableViewDataSource implementation:

```
public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return messageModels.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let model = messageModel[indexPath.row]


    let cellIdentifier = /* Name of the UITableViewCell this model is associated with */


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)


    model.configure(cell: cell)
    return cell
}
```

Is there anyway I can archive this goal?

Comment: This could be the answer of your question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpTNaBUFkno

Comment: That doesn't help me with my goal, his method is only effective when the table view has only 1 type of cell. In my cases I need to display different cell types

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use a Protocol to set the type of the cell and not use a if statement or switch inside of the ```cellForRowAt``` ?

Comment: If statements. It can become huge and not readable as number of cells grows.

Comment: Then use a switch statement to set the cell type for different cases.

Comment: @Len_X, my goal is to create a general controller that display the messages passed to it. And the job of determine/configure the cell is off to the message model themselves, this way I don't have to modify my view controller when there are new cell types.

Answer (score 6):

Just imagine your data would be like:

```
class TableViewModel {
    let items: [Any] = [
        User(name: "John Smith", imageName: "user3"),
        "Hi, this is a message text. Tra la la. Tra la la.",
        Bundle.main.url(forResource: "beach@2x", withExtension: "jpg")!,
        User(name: "Jessica Wood", imageName: "user2"),
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    ]
}
```

So normally we would implement it in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method with many `if let ...`

One way to prevent this is to use generic types. Generic programming is an excellent way to avoid boilerplate code and helps to define errors during compilation time.

> Generic code enables you to write flexible, reusable functions and
>   types that can work with any type, subject to requirements that you
>   define. You can write code that avoids duplication and expresses its
>   intent in a clear, abstracted manner.
>   [Apple Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Let’s make a first protocol that each cell should conform to.

```
protocol ConfigurableCell {
    associatedtype DataType
    func configure(data: DataType)
}

//example of UserCell
class UserCell: UITableViewCell, ConfigurableCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var avatarView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    func configure(data user: User) {
        avatarView.image = UIImage(named: user.imageName)
        userNameLabel.text = user.name
    }
}
```

Now we can create a generic cell configurator that will configure our table cells.

```
protocol CellConfigurator {
    static var reuseId: String { get }
    func configure(cell: UIView)
}

class TableCellConfigurator<CellType: ConfigurableCell, DataType>: CellConfigurator where CellType.DataType == DataType, CellType: UITableViewCell {
    static var reuseId: String { return String(describing: CellType.self) }

    let item: DataType

    init(item: DataType) {
        self.item = item
    }

    func configure(cell: UIView) {
        (cell as! CellType).configure(data: item)
    }
}
```

Now we need some adjustments to our ViewModel:

```
typealias UserCellConfigurator = TableCellConfigurator<UserCell, User>
typealias MessageCellConfigurator = TableCellConfigurator<MessageCell, String>
typealias ImageCellConfigurator = TableCellConfigurator<ImageCell, URL>

class TableViewModel {
    let items: [CellConfigurator] = [
        UserCellConfigurator(item: User(name: "John Smith", imageName: "user3")),
        MessageCellConfigurator(item: "Hi, this is a message text. Tra la la. Tra la la."),
        ImageCellConfigurator(item: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "beach@2x", withExtension: "jpg")!),
        UserCellConfigurator(item: User(name: "Jessica Wood", imageName: "user2")),
        MessageCellConfigurator(item: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."),
    ]
}
```

That’s it!

You can add new cells easily without a need to edit your ViewController’s code.

Let’s add a WarningCell to our table view.

1.Conform to ConfigurableCell protocol.
2.Add TableCellConfigurator for that cell in ViewModel’s class.

```
class WarningCell: UITableViewCell, ConfigurableCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

    func configure(data message: String) {
        messageLabel.text = message
    }
}

//cell configurator for WarningCell
TableCellConfigurator<WarningCell, String>(item: "This is a serious warning!")
```

For further information follow this [link](https://medium.com/chili-labs/configuring-multiple-cells-with-generics-in-swift-dcd5e209ba16)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: How will you edit the data model from didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: How can i update data model in table view cell